# cant figure out the running time of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have been asked to write algorithm for this problem: we are given array A and we want to know if there is any two elements U and L in array which U+L=K

I wrote my algorithm like this:

```
while(first<last)
{
  if(arr[first]+arr[last]==k)
     return true
  else if(arr[first]+arr[last]<k)
     last=last-1;
  else
     first++;
}
return false   

}
```

**But the problem is that what is the running time of this algorithm ?is it O(nlogn)? if yes why?and if not how can I implement it in O(nlogn)?**

Comment: Are you 100% sure that alg solves the problem?

Comment: which language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running time of your algorithm is `O(N)` since in the worst case, you just end up iterating over the whole array.

Though your algorithm would not solve the problem. For example consider `{9,1,3,4,2}`. In this case if `k` would be `12`, it would return false. For your algorithm the input array should be sorted first and then passed to the algorithm, which will take `O(NlogN)` in the worst case.

A much faster solution will be however to use something like `HashMap` to solve the problem in `O(N)` time.

Comment: Thanks can you explain how to implement it in O(nlogn) because I am asked to implement it in nlogn?

Comment: @user2860721 you would need to sort the array first using sorting algorithms which takes O(NlogN) time in worst case like Mergesort (Arrays.sort in java uses Mergesort) and then give it to your algorithm

Comment: Great I totally forgot to sort array first:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example of the alg in python where the result is false, but there is two elements in the list that fulfilles the U+L=k

```
def testArray(a, k):
    first = 0
    last = len(a) - 1

    while (first < last):
        print first, last
        if (a[first] + a[last] == k):
            return True
        elif (a[first] + a[last] < k):
            last=last-1
        else:
            first=first+1
    return False

a = [3, 1, 5, 3, 6]
print testArray(a, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks, from your post and hrv post I understood that first I should sort the array:)